# Connect two framed walls with a 2x4? (See video)

Tags: walls, framing, code-compliance

I have two interior walls that are 3.5” apart in a tight area. I’d like to use a single 2x4 to connect them to save space on both sides. Is this up to IRC/IBC code? Neither wall will carry electric or other utilities.

Here is a [video link](https://youtu.be/LDsnrDaCEEc) and below is a drawing.

[image]

Drawing 2 is rotated 180* (so north is south): [image]

Comment: Which direction is up in the diagram? How did you get into this situation in the first place?

Comment: Should be okay, but why.  Is there something that stops you from making a single wall, need to bypass something?  Can see not starting over the window opening, but want the extra width.

Comment: @keshlam  The video does show a window in the way.  If I were better might want to do a curve to miss the window( can dream can't I).

Comment: My only concern would be egress. Is this a bedroom with a requirement of an operable window of X width/height? And I'm curious as to how/why this solution came about, but don't feel obliged...

Comment: It’s a powder room that I’m adding to the first floor of my townhome. The window is only 30 inches from the wall and I’d like to have ~33” inside the powder room for the toilet.

Comment: Can you give accurate dimensions from behind the proposed toilet? (Corner to close side of window trim.)

Comment: Was gonna say that an overly fussy inspector might give you a hard time about the requirement that toilets have 15" clear from the centerline, but since the bowl of the toilet will have that clear space, it *probably* won't be a thing.